# There exists $v_0 \in V$ such that $\forall v \in V \space\space T(v)=\lambda v+ \alpha(v) v_0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space and $\lambda$ a constant real number. Suppose that $T: V \to V$ is a linear map and $\alpha: V \to \mathbb R$ is a linear functional on $V$.
Suppose that for every $v \in Ker(\alpha)$ we have $T(v)=\lambda v$.

> Prove that:   There exists $v_0 \in V$ such that  $\forall v \in V
>  \space\space T(v)=\lambda v+ \alpha(v) v_0$

I'm completely blind! I don't know where to start! The question says if $v \in Ker(\alpha)$, $T(v)=\lambda v$. So, If $\alpha(v)=0$,  then $T(v)=\lambda v$. But how is this related to the existence of $v_0$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the operator $T - \lambda I$ (where $I \colon V \rightarrow V$ is the identity operator). If $T - \lambda I = 0$, take $v_0 = 0$. If $T - \lambda I \neq 0$, choose $u_0 \in V$ such that $(T - \lambda I)(u_0) \neq 0$. Note that this implies that $u_0 \notin \ker(\alpha)$ so by replacing $u_0$ with $\frac{u_0}{\alpha(u_0)}$ we can assume that $\alpha(u_0) = 1$. Set $v_0 = (T - \lambda I)(u_0)$ so we have

$$ T(u_0) = \lambda u_0 + v_0. $$

Finally, for any $v \in V$ we have

$$ T(v) = T(v - \alpha(v) u_0 + \alpha(v) u_0) = T(v - \alpha(v) u_0) + T(\alpha(v) u_0) = \\ \lambda(v - \alpha(v) u_0) + \alpha(v) (\lambda u_0 +  v_0) = \lambda v + \alpha(v) v_0$$

as required (where we used the fact that $v - \alpha(v) u_0 \in \ker(\alpha)$ so $T(v - \alpha(v) u_0) = \lambda (v - \alpha(v) u_0)$).

Comment: Excuse me, what is "direct sum decomposition"?

Comment: @PaoloMolina: It means every vector $v \in V$ can be written uniquely as $v = v_1 + v_2$ with $v_1 \in \ker(\alpha)$ and $v_2 \in \operatorname{span} \{ u_0 \}$.

Comment: @PaoloMolina: I've edited my answer so that it doesn't use the notion of direct sum decomposition.

Comment: Thank you :) I really appreciate that :)

Comment: You say $T(v - \alpha(v) u_o) = \lambda(v - \alpha (v) u_0)$, aren't you saying $v - \alpha (v) u_0 \in \ker (\alpha)$? It's because $v = v_k + \alpha(v) u_0 - \alpha(v) u_0$ where $v_k \in \ker (\alpha)$?

Comment: @Hawk: Well, $v - \alpha(v) u_0$ is in $\ker(\alpha)$ because $\alpha(v - \alpha(v) u_0) = \alpha(v) - \alpha(v) \alpha(u_0) = 0$ since $\alpha(u_0) = 1$.

Comment: The basic idea is that if $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space and $\alpha \neq 0$ is a linear functional on $V$ then $\ker(\alpha)$ is an $n-1$-dimensional subspace of $V$ and we can choose any $u_0$ with $\alpha(u_0) \neq 0$ to complement $\ker(\alpha)$ so that it becomes the whole of $V$ ($V = \ker(\alpha) \oplus \operatorname{span} \{ u_0 \}$). Since the OP is not familiar with direct sums, I didn't mention it in my answer but this is the motivation for choosing such $u_0$ and doing the calculation above.